# pandas Styler. How to ignore the index column from the rendered HTML

Tags: python, css, pandas, pandas-styles

I am trying to use the string generated from rendering a styler in an email message.  Seems really hard to get this to ignore the dataframe index.

```
table_styles = [dict(selector="tbody tr th", props=[("display", "none")]),
st=df.style.set_table_styles(table_styles)
st.render()
```

I have been able to sort of make it work with the display none CSS setting, but it works differently on different devices based on CSS support level.
Isn't there a way to make the index payload just go away ?

Comment: Hi, I am having similar issue. Did you have any luck solving it?

Answer (score 3):

styler.hide_index() method is deprecated in favour of `Styler.hide(axis='index') (version 1.4.0)

for me  `df.style.hide(axis='index')` works.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same solution as yours and I am facing the same issue as you were (display is different on different devices). I am just writing down the partial solution here to help someone who is in search of the way to do it.

if you do `html.render().split('\n')` you will be able to get the class structure related to the first column and index( if you have already used resent_index).

Styles can then be defined to get rid of those columns using CSS property of display.

```
# define the style related to first column and index here
# first-element : when index =True, 
# second element: default index of the table generated by the Style
styles = [ 
  dict(selector = ".col0", props = [('display', 'none')]), 
  dict(selector = "th:first-child", props = [('display', 'none')])
 ]

 # set the table styles here
 table.set_table_styles(styles)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to pandas styling documentation section: [Hiding the Index or Columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) it is enough to use `.hide_index()`. In your case it would be:

```
table_styles = [dict(selector="tbody tr th", props=[("display", "none")]),
st=df.style.set_table_styles(table_styles).hide_index()
st.render()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure we had the same issue but my problem was to save a df into an HTML file using `.style.render()`. I've tried to use the CSS style but it wouldn't work. The solution I used is so simple I didn't think about it, I basically run `.hide_index()` , like this:

```
html = ts_volume_html.style.format({'total_ops': "{:.2f}", 'read_ops': '{:.2f}','read_data(bps)':'{:.2f}',
                        'read_latency(us)': "{:.2f}", 'write_ops': '{:.2f}','write_data(bps)':'{:.2f}',
                        'write_latency(us)': "{:.2f}", 'other_ops': '{:.2f}','other_latency(us)':'{:.2f}', \
                        .set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"')\
                        .set_precision(2).set_properties(**{'font-size': '10pt', 'font-family': 'Courier New'})\
                        .hide_index().background_gradient(cmap=cm).set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('font-size', '10pt')]}]).render()
```

I then saved the 'html' str into an html file.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.23.0 pandas comes with a [styler.hide_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide_index.html) function, chain it with other methods to be applied as the returned object is still going to be a styler object

If hide_index() is not available, try updating your pandas library